# regex two math operators side by side

Tags: javascript, regex

I want flag something like this as invalid because it contains two mathematical operators next to each other `(1)* + (2) ///` ie. the `*+` and `//`

Comment: That was a torn flag..Don't take it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work? this will also match with any number of whitespace between two operators

```
/[\+\-\*\/]\s*[\+\-\*\/]/
```